# Drupal render results in block after posting form

Tags: drupal, drupal-forms, drupal-blocks

I have a form that is created in a **block** in drupal, what I would like to do is display a result of the calculated values passed to the form in the same block.

1. I render the form using

> _block_view
>       $blocks['content'] = drupal_render(drupal_get_form('form_name'));

1. the form is displayed
2. on form submit I do a calculation on the posted values
3. from here I want to display the result in the original block

How do I capture the result and display it, or ideally display it under the form retaining the forms values?

Comment: You should capture the values in the form itself and add a form item element that will display the result in the same block/form

Answer (score 0):

OK what I did was add 
`$form_state ['redirect'] = FALSE;` 
to the submit handler, and the form populated itself, I then added a new form field with a readonly attribute and set `#value` to the calculated value utilising the values passed back inside $form_state['input']... also I omitted `drupal_render(` from the `$blocks['content']=` setting call above as it was not required

Comment: I need to do something similar, but I need more help than what you asked for. Can you post the whole source code please?